# In Inkscape how to change stroke thickness for a grouped object

Tags: inkscape, stroke

Let's say I have object A with stroke thickness x, and object B with stroke thickness x as well. I group them to make a single object. Now I want to change the border thickness of this object, to make it thicker. But with the inner stroke thickness unchanged. Is there anyway to do it?

The only way I can think of is to copy the object and increase the thickness of all strokes on the copy and place it precisely behind the original. Although it seems to work, it doesn't feel as though it is the correct way.

Comment: When you have two objects, grouped or not, there is no 'inner' strokes, just the outer strokes of each object.  I played with the paths (combine, include, etc.) but those tended to leave me with one objects (with the same fill, and the inner strokes vanished).  Good question, I could see how the effect would be useful for sure.  Hopefully someone has a procedure to pull it off. :)

Comment: My purpose is to make "cartoon"-like images. If you look at Hanna-Barbara style cartoons (dexter's lab, johnny bravo etc) they have thick outer strokes and thin inner strokes.

Comment: Weird, that's _exactly_ the usage I was thinking it would be good for. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your grouped objects are closed curves, you can

1. Duplicate the group,
2. Use "path > combine"
3. Put the combined path in the background

The combined path is the ***silhouette*** of your object. This silhouette can have the thick lines and fill color, while the other group would have no fill and the thinner lines. The outer lines would still be duplicate (with thinner on top of thicker), unless you erase them by hand (hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click inside the group).